# Bootstrap modal doesn't close after resetting HTML body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a printModal and a closeModal buttons on my bootstrap modal. The modal doesn't close after the print logic runs.

**Step 1:** Click on printModal after popup is loaded. (works fine).
**Step 2:** Close the browser print dialog (works fine, the print dialog closes and bootstrap modal is still visible).
**Step 3:** Click on closeModal (FAILs, modal doesn't close).

If I click on closeModal before I click on printModal, it works fine. It only doesn't work after printModal is executed first.

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div id="modalContent" class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
    // more html


        <div class"buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="printButton" class="btn-lg" value="Print">
            <input type="submit" id="closeButton" class="btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('#myModal').on('click', 'input#printButton', function () {

            var myCopy = document.body.innerHTML;
            var printThis = document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printThis;

            window.print();

            document.body.innerHTML = myCopy;

        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you change the whole HTML code of your page and also the whole DOM with this code:

```
document.body.innerHTML = printThis;
```

The javascript functions that were bound to the DOM elements are now gone, so does the `click` event on your close button.

What you can do is to change the css for printing so only the modal content is visible.

Alternatively you can open a popup, add the modal content there, print it and close it afterwards. Example with a popup:

```
var printPopup = window.open('');
printPopup.document.write(printThis);
printPopup.document.write(/ add some css or include a css file/);
printPopup.print();
```

Note that popups are not good for user expirience, so you should try the css modification aproach first.

Comment: Makes sense, is there anyway to rebind javascript functions without reloading the page?

Comment: You could detach the child elements of body with jQuery's `detach` https://api.jquery.com/detach/, then attach your modal content and after that reattach the stuff again. But again just adding a css class to body and adjust the styles would be less prone to errors and easier

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your `input` to `button`, as shown [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#live-demo).

So it'll look like this:

```
<div class"buttons">
   <input type="submit" id="printButton" class="btn-lg" value="Print">
   <button id="closeButton" class="btn-lg" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not work as the JS and DOM binding is broken.